# ¿Es posible hacer referencia a los datos de un POD diferente que existe en mi clúster y agregarlo a otro POD?

Tags: variables, kubernetes, variables-de-configuración, pods

espero que alguien me ayuda con esta duda. Seria de mucha ayuda.

¿Es posible extraer los datos de un POD diferente que existe en mi clúster y agregarlo a este POD prueba?. Actualmente, este manifiesto solo extrae datos del mismo POD y quiera hacer referencia a datos de otro POD. ¿Eso es posible?

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: prueba
spec:
 containers:
   - name: prueba
     image: nginx:alpine
     env:
       - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
         valueFrom:
           fieldRef:
             fieldPath: metadata.namespace    #namespace del mismo pod
       - name: MY_POD_IP
         valueFrom:
           fieldRef:
             fieldPath: status.podIP       #ip  del mismo pod
```

Estos datos (IP, NAMESPACE) son del mismo POD. ¿Algún método para agregar datos de un Pod diferente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]